# Как использовать формул ARRAYFORMULA, в моем случае для построчного вычисления сумм

Tags: google-spreadsheet

В первой колонке есть фразы. Хочу перевести их в произвольные цифры и сложить.
Получилось все сделать с помощью формулы:
=sum(split(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(B3;"[{-}]";"3");"[Ф-Яф-я]";"3");"[А-На-н]";"8");"[О-Уо-у]";"6");" "))

Нужно сделать так, чтобы она растягивалась вниз с помощью ARRAYFORMULA, чтобы не приходилось вручную ее растягивать для каждой строки. Пробывал сделать это примерно с помощью такой формулы =MMULT(REGEXREPLACE(G5:H6;"[Ф-Яф-я]";"3");TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(G1:H1)^0))) Но этот вариант не работает... Если убрать REGEXREPLACE он суммирует построчно значения ячеек, но я хотел бы вместить все в одну формулу выше, чтобы ничего не растягивать вручную, таблицы очень большие.

Либо подойдет любая формула, которая слово или фразу может представить суммой (именно суммой, не просто замена букв на цифры). Цель - сделать выборку из первой колонке значений, используя сумму цифр и функцию [image: VLOOKUP]

Спасибо

Comment: Вы уже пробовали указать вместо `B3` целый диапазон, например, `B3:B1000` и завершить ввод формулы Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Comment: указание диапазона вместо B3, например, B3:B1000 не работает, максимум предлагает автозаполнение, что не подходит

Comment: Пришлите пример Таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это

```
=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
  TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(B3:B,"[{-}]","3"),"[Ф-Яф-я]","3"),"[А-На-н]","8"),"[О-Уо-у]","6")," "),) + 0),
  "select " & "sum(Col" & JOIN("), sum(Col", SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(B3:B),1,1)) & ")"
))),,2)
```

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HZqzBxoOh66toYmgIOwZKFYSbLzXVCsLNGKJR0WNm-w/edit#gid=853234742&range=B3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]